# Having trouble registering array input fields using React Hook Form

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hook-form

I seem to be missing some sort of connection between my fields and my typing here. I'm using React Hook Form and registering inputs for a submission for adding a new company contact. Here is the interface for my form fields:

```
export interface AddClientFormData {
  clientData: ClientAddRequest;
}
```

the ClientAddRequest interface looks like this:

```
export interface ClientAddRequest {
    companyName?: string;
    address?: AddressAddRequest;
    contacts?: Array<ContactAddRequest>;
}
```

and the ContactAddRequest interface looks like this:

```
export interface ContactAddRequest {
    name?: string;
    title?: string;
    email?: string;
    phone?: string;
}
```

I am able to register the companyName and address fields without any problems. Here is an example of how I'm using them:

```
          <input
           className="l-add-client-form__company-details__company-name"
            placeholder="Company Name"
            {...register("clientData.companyName", { required: true })}
          />
          {errors.clientData?.companyName && (
            <span> This field is required </span>
          )}
          <input
            className="l-add-client-form__company-details__company-address"
            placeholder="Primary Address"
            {...register("clientData.address.addressLine1", { required: true })}
          />
          {errors.clientData?.address?.addressLine1 && (
            <span> This field is required </span>
          )}
          <input
            className="l-add-client-form__company-details__company-city"
            placeholder="City"
            {...register("clientData.address.city", { required: true })}
          />
          {errors.clientData?.address?.city && (
            <span> This field is required </span>
          )}
          <input
            className="l-add-client-form__company-details__company-state"
            placeholder="State"
            {...register("clientData.address.state", { required: true })}
          />
          {errors.clientData?.address?.state && (
            <span> This field is required </span>
          )}
          <input
            className="l-add-client-form__company-details__company-zip"
            placeholder="Zip Code"
            {...register("clientData.address.zip", { required: true })}
          />
          {errors.clientData?.address?.zip && (
            <span> This field is required </span>
          )}
```

However, I'm not sure how to properly register the input fields for the ContactAddAddress fields, since it is an array. I tried to utilizing indexing but I'm still getting an error that states `"Argument of type 'clientData.contacts[${number}].name' is not assignable to parameter of type '"clientData.companyName" | "clientData" | "locationData" | "clientData.address" | "clientData.contacts" | "clientData.address.addressLine1" | "clientData.address.addressLine2" | ... 14 more ... | "locationData.name"'.ts(2345)"`

This is how I was trying to use indexing but it is not working:

```
        {contacts.map((contact, index) => (
        <div className="l-add-client-form__contact-details">
          <input
            className="l-add-client-form__contact-details__name"
            placeholder="Contact Name"
            {...register(`clientData.contacts[${index}].name`, { required: true })}
          />
          {errors.clientData?.contacts && <span> This field is required </span>}

    [...rest of the code...]
```

How do I properly achieve this? Thanks in advance!